# Solving $2\cos^2 x-2\sin^2 x-2\cos x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$f(x) = 2\cos^2 x-2\sin^2 x-2\cos x$$

Need values of x that which make $f(x) = 0$

Tried $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ with no luck

Really just need a hint that could bring me in the right direction

Thanks

EDIT: Solution thanks to everyones help! :D 
$$f(x) = 2\cos^2 x-2\sin^2 x-2\cos x$$
$$0 = 2\cos^2 x-2 + 2\cos^2 x-2\cos x$$
$$0 = 4\cos^2 x-2\cos x - 2$$
$$\cos x = 2\pm \sqrt {-2^2-4(4)(-2)\over8}$$
$$\cos x =  {2 \pm 6\over 8}$$
$$\cos x = {-1\over2}, 1$$
$$x = 2n\pi \pm{2\pi\over3}$$

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot accept more than one answers but you can still appreciate help of everyone by up-voting their answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

> Use $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$

**Update:**

$$\cos x=-\frac{1}{2},1$$

$$\cos x=-\dfrac12=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)\implies x=2k\pi\pm\dfrac{2\pi}3$$

$$\cos x=1\implies x=2k\pi$$

Comment: UGH! Finally! Thank you so much. I didn't think i'd ever be as frustrated as I was tonight about a math question. I consider myself to be pretty good at math and to have a question completely kick my a** is just annoying. Thank you so much again, also thank you to @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\cos x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$$

$$\implies2x=2m\pi\pm x$$ where $m$ is any integer

Taking the '-' sign, $3x=2m\pi\iff x=\dfrac{2m\pi}3\  \ \  \ (1)$

Taking the '+' sign, $x=2m\pi $ which is a proper subset of $(1)$

Comment: @Integrator, $$\cos x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$$  right?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment as I thought it to be useless after @Integrator's answer :-)

Comment: @Singhal, I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: @Integrator, I always prefer using identities to solving polynomial equations.

Comment: Your anwser definitely works, but the how is what has me lost. After applying the identity I end up with $$2cos2x-2cosx=0$$ then ?

Comment: @discretelogman, With the latest version of the problem, either $$\cos x=1\implies x=2m\pi$$ or $$\cos x=-\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac{2\pi}3\implies x=2n\pi\pm\dfrac{2\pi}3$$